# Set Margin to Multiple ImageView Programmatically

Tags: android

I have two imageView in LinearLayout and I want to set margin programmatically,but problem is that margin apply only on one imageView. Here is my .xml file..,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/ivMarginBottom"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/image_round"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageOne"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/ivMarginBottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:src="@drawable/icongallery" 
        />

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imageTwo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:src="@drawable/icongallery" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my .java code..,

```
@Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) {
        int left_margin = progress;
        int top_margin = progress;
        int right_margin = progress;
        int bottom_margin = progress;

        MarginLayoutParams marginParams1 = new MarginLayoutParams(imageOne.getLayoutParams());
        marginParams1.setMargins(left_margin, top_margin, right_margin, bottom_margin);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(marginParams1);
        imageOne.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);

        MarginLayoutParams marginParams2 = new MarginLayoutParams(imageTwo.getLayoutParams());
        marginParams2.setMargins(left_margin, top_margin, right_margin, bottom_margin);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(marginParams2);
        imageTwo.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first get Layout params like this

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp =
                (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
```

then set margins

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the following code:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.setMargins(left_margin, top_margin, right_margin, bottom_margin);
    imageOne.setLayoutParams(lp);
    imageTwo.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:

```
int left_margin = progress;
int top_margin = progress;
int right_margin = progress;
int bottom_margin = progress;

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1);
layoutParams.setMargins(left_margin, top_margin, right_margin, bottom_margin);
imageOne.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
imageTwo.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```